# How to use RAII to acquire resources of class?

Tags: c++, raii

There is example that shows that using RAII this way:

```
class File_ptr{
//...
   File* p;
   int* i; 
   public:
      File_ptr(const char* n, const char* s){
         i=new int[100];
         p=fopen(n,a); // imagine fopen might throws
      }
      ~File_ptr(){fclose(p);}
}

void use_file(const char* fn){
    File_ptr(fn,"r");
}
```

is safe. but my question is: what if there is exception thrown in `p=fopen(n,a);` then memory allocated to `i` is not returned. Is this right to assume that `RAII` tells you then each time you want `X` to be safe then all resources acquired by `X` must be allocated on stack? And if `X.a` is being created then resources of `a` must also be placed on stack? and again, and again, I mean finally if there is some resource placed on heap how it could be handled with RAII? If it is not mine class i.e.

Comment: Separate your concerns, have one resource managing class per resource and one class aggregating managed resources.

Comment: `fopen` is a `C` function so it won't throw any exception because `C` doesn't have exception

Comment: it is example, imagine it throws

Comment: The fix is to change `int* i` to something like `std::vector<int> i`. That is, to use RAII.

Comment: If you had a function that throws an exception you have two options handle the exception or keep throwing it up. Its fine to have a constructor that throws.

Comment: I know vector solves it, but RAII is not dependent on stl

Comment: It is dependent on the Rule of Three or Five, though.

Comment: @authority: You could use a smart pointer or any class object that cleans up the memory in the destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treating this as an intellectual exercise where you don't want to use `std::vector`, you need to divide your classes up so they have a single responsibility. Here's my "integer array" class. Its responsibility is to manage the memory for an integer array.

```
class IntArray {
public:
    IntArray() : ptr_(new int[100]) {}
    ~IntArray() { delete[] ptr_; }
    IntArray(const IntArray&) = delete; // making copyable == exercise for reader
    IntArray& operator=(const IntArray&) = delete;
    // TODO: accessor?
private:
    int* ptr_;
};
```

Here is my file handling class. Its responsibility is to manage a `FILE*`.

```
class FileHandle {
public:
    FileHandle(const char* name, const char* mode)
     : fp_(fopen(name, mode))
    {
        if (fp_ == 0)
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open file");
    }
    ~FileHandle() {
        fclose(fp_); // squelch errors
    }
    FileHandle(const FileHandle&) = delete;
    FileHandle& operator=(const FileHandle&) = delete;
    // TODO: accessor?
private:
    FILE* fp_;
};
```

Note, that I convert my construction error to an exception; `fp_` being a valid file pointer is an invariant that I wish to maintain so I abort construction if I cannot set this invariant up.

Now, makeing `File_ptr` exception safe is easy and the class needs no complex resource management.

```
class File_ptr {
private:
    FileHandle p;
    IntArray i; 
public:
    File_ptr(const char* n, const char* s)
     : p(n, s)
     , i()
    {}
};
```

Note the lack of any user-declared destructor, copy assignment operator or copy constructor. I can swap the order of the members and in either case it doesn't matter which constructor throws.

Comment: thanks. what if in your File_ptr class constructor i() throws? destructor ~IntArray() for vaiable File_ptr.i will be called because it is on stack, no matter than constructor failed and it is not considered initialized? is it considered constructed though? I have seen that constructor must return to consider object as created

Comment: @authority: If `IntArray()` throws during the construction of `i` then `p` will be cleaned up as the first part of stack unwinding. (Because the initialization of `i` is ordered after the initialization of `p`, we know that `p` must have been successfully initialized by the time the initialization of `i` throws an exception. This means that `p` can and must be cleaned up.)

Comment: yes, and my question is what with memory allocated by IntArray, delete[]ptr_ is not called then. And in generall this is again same case: IntArray should be constructed like File_ptr to allocate on stack, so objects are for sure deleted even when it throws, right? I mean at the last end I never escpape from doing something that will not be deleted (unless I use try(){}catch() ofcourse)

Comment: please explain me this, this is essence of my question

Comment: @authority: There is no memory allocated by `IntArray` in that situation; it threw an exception! That is why it is so fundamentally important to have you resource managing classes manage **one** resource each.

Comment: ok, another issue: assume it was this memory allocated - object IntArray i in class File_ptr is not considered constructed, so File_ptr is not considered constructed: is destructor of File_ptr called or not?

Comment: No, the destructor `~File_ptr` is only called on instances of `File_ptr` that are fully constructed. If any part of the construction of the `File_ptr` fails then the destructor will not be called on that object.

Answer (score 11):

The whole point of RAII is to NOT assign any resources (like the `int`-array) to dangling pointers. Instead, use `std::vector` or assign the array pointer to something like `std::unique_ptr`. This way the resources will be destroyed as exceptions occur.

And no, you don't have to use STL, but to make use of RAII, the lowest base-resources (like heap allocated arrays) have to be created using RAII as well and the easiest way to do this is to use STL rather than writing your own smart-pointer or vectors.

Comment: Unfortunately the standard library doesn't provide any RAII facilities except for memory. They should have at least included something for files.

Comment: Well std::fstream does just that. But one could argue that a stream is not exactly the same as a simple filehandle. With C++11, threading based objects like mutex and lock are added. But yeah, STL is a bit lacking in comparison to other frameworks. It's more like a best practice-collection of extended core language features.

Comment: As an aside, you probably have never used the [STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library), which is the name of the library that inspired many features of the `std` library.

Comment: @Yakk: You're right, how come I have never heard of that. But it seems STL is used very often as a synonym for the std-library since std-library is in fact a `std`-named, template-based, library. Besides, OP mentioned STL in one of the comments.

Answer (score 3):

if exception happen after the `new`, you have to catch the exception and delete the pointer in the constructor then re-throw in this case, the destructor will not be called since the object is never constructed.

otherwise if `i` is a std::vector, it will clean up automatically

Comment: I know vector solves it, but RAII is not dependent on stl. What in general case

Comment: @authority in the general case, use one RAII object per resource. Vectors are just one example of such a type.

Answer (score 3):

One way to handle this is to put everything that might be invalidated by an exception into a local variable which itself uses RAII, then assign to your members at the end when it's safe.

```
class File_ptr{
//...
   File* p;
   int* i; 
   public:
      File_ptr(const char* n, const char* s) i(NULL), p(NULL) {
         unique_ptr<int> temp_i=new int[100];  // might throw std::bad_alloc
         p=fopen(n,a); // imagine fopen might throws
         // possibility of throwing an exception is over, safe to set members now
         i = temp_i.release();
      }
      ~File_ptr(){fclose(p);}
}
```

For more information see [Exception Safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety).

Answer (score 2):

If you know it throws, put it in a `try-catch`.

```
File_ptr(const char* n, const char* s) {
    i=new int[100];
    try {
        p=fopen(n,a); // imagine fopen might throws
    } catch(...) {
         delete[] i;
         throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the original exception should be rethrown.

Answer (score 1):

```
File_ptr(const char* n, const char* s)
{
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> sp(new int[100]);
  p = fopen(n, s);
  i = sp.release();
}
```